# How to remove MainLayout from my Sub-Page?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

How to remove MainLayout from my Sub-Page ?
when I create a subpage in my project, it create with the MainLayout page, how to remove this automate call from my sub-page ? note that I'm using blazor and .net 5 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a AnnonymousLayout razor component like this

AnnonymousLayout.razor

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    @Body
</div>
```

And you can use it in a page where you do not want main layout, like this

```
@page "/yourpage"
@layout AnnonymousLayout
```